# Is there anyway to copy list of files which exist inside the csv with aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, aws-cli, extract

I have one folder called `all-files` on s3 bucket which has 35K files. I have one CSV file (errors.csv) which has 1K filenames and this filenames are sub-set of 35K filenames. I need to copy 1k files (which are from csv) from 35K `all-files` folder to some new folder called `errors` on same bucket.

Is this possible anyway? If yes, how?

I tried soemthing with `cp` command with `include` pattern but it seems does not support input from csv file.

Comment: A simple bash loop over the file names from the csv should be enough.

Comment: @Marcin how will that copy to s3? can you please explain?

Comment: I will provide basic example.

Comment: Personally, I do this by putting the filenames in an Excel spreadsheet, then build a formula that inserts the filename into `="aws s3 cp s3://bucket/"&A1&" s3://bucket/folder/"`. Then, use Fill Down to populate the 1000 rows, copy them out and paste them into a command line. Done! (I suggest you test a couple of rows before pasting all 1000 rows.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein how to handle if I need double quote before s3 like "s3://bucket/folder with space"

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I could manage this by adding `" & CHAR(34) & "` for " char

Comment: In Excel, use two quotes (`""`) to represent a quote. For example: `="aws s3 cp ""s3://bucket/"&A1&""" ""s3://bucket/folder/"""`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't specific if you use Linux or not, I assume Linux.

The most **basic** way of doing this in `bash` is as follows (you haven't provided any example file content to work with):

```
# populate example `/tmp/files.csv` file:

cat >/tmp/files.csv << EOF
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
file7
EOF
```

Read **line-by-line** from `/tmp/files.csv` and execute the `aws s3 mv`:

```
while read file; do
  echo "aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/${file} s3://<otherbucket>/${file}"
done < /tmp/files.csv
```

This results in:

```
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file1 s3://<otherbucket>/file1
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file2 s3://<otherbucket>/file2
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file3 s3://<otherbucket>/file3
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file4 s3://<otherbucket>/file4
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file5 s3://<otherbucket>/file5
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file6 s3://<otherbucket>/file6
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file7 s3://<otherbucket>/file7
```

More complex examples, would involve running the commands **concurrently**, by moving few files at the same time.

An example of **moving 3 files at the same time**:

```
cat /tmp/files.csv | xargs -L 3 echo | while read files; do

    echo -e "\nMove a set of files at the same time:"

    for file in ${files}; do
        echo "aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/${file} s3://<otherbucket>/${file}" &
    done

    wait 

done
```

Output:

```
Move a set of files at the same time:
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file1 s3://<otherbucket>/file1
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file2 s3://<otherbucket>/file2
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file3 s3://<otherbucket>/file3

Move a set of files at the same time:
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file4 s3://<otherbucket>/file4
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file5 s3://<otherbucket>/file5
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file6 s3://<otherbucket>/file6

Move a set of files at the same time:
aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file7 s3://<otherbucket>/file7
```

Comment: Hi @Marcin, thanks for providing solution for this. I was trying this but it seems giving me `does not existerror occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key` any idea? Also my echo command does not print output like yours, it just print first part like `aws s3 mv s3://<bucket>/file1`

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia This is only en example. Wihtout know exactly how does your csv looks like, its impossible to give precise answer. You can update your question with all the relevant csv examples, and the your modified code how you execute them.

Comment: csv file is nothing but single line for file name, even I tried the same by changing it to txt file, I am not expert at bash but there problem in variable assigning part, my echo is not priting result as expected. Have you tried above exactly?

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia The format is important. If the file names contains spaces, or other non-printable characters that can lead to issues in bash.

Comment: it has spaces but even if I test with 1.txt as filename, it gives same result

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia Can you update your question with those new details - test, code which you use, example csv file and output you are getting.

Comment: I have tried exact your steps for creating csv then its working so accepting answe.. but my csv has same file name (which is generated from Windows) then it's not working. I am not sure why but my problem solved in other way mentioned by JohnRotenstein in comments

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia Thanks. And am glad it worked out at the end.